# Is there an term for various finder syntax

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

Is there a term for this type of syntax?

```
page.find(:xpath, '//span[class("blah1 blah2 blah3Button")]')
```

Is there a term for this type of syntax?

```
page.find('span.blah1.blah2.blah3.Button')
```

Is it merely explicit vs. implicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are both just method calls, there is nothing special about the syntax.